# How can I tease apart the role two variables play in an outcome?

Tags: regression, anova, t-test

I was wondering what type of statistical test I can use to find the role each variable plays in this scenario.

We have an experiment set up with four groups (we are using drosophila flies).

Group 1: Young, wild type flies
Group 2: Old, wild type flies
Group 3: Young, mutant flies
Group 4: Old, mutant flies

We are calculating average walking speed (one of many assays).

We readily expect group 4 to have the slowest flies. Is there a way we could find out how much of the loss of speed (compared to group 1) is due to age and how much is due to the mutation?

Comment: Try regression with walking speed as dependent variable and age and mutation as independent variables.